# jQuery AJAX response always returns nothing

Tags: ajax, web-services, jquery, asp.net-3.5

The following code returns a blank response no matter whether or not the Function exists, or even the Web Service file entirely:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/ws.asmx/HelloWorld"
    , type: "POST"
    , contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    , data: '{ FileName: "' + filename + '" }'
    , dataType: 'json'
    , success: function (data) {

    }
});
```

Why is this?

Also, might be worth noting, `$.load()` works fine!

Comment: What if you create a `<form method="POST">` and try it that way? Does it return anything?

Answer (score 4):

Your error is that you try to construct JSON data manually and do this in the wrong way:

```
'{ FileName: "' + filename + '" }'
```

You should fix the code at least to the following

```
'{ "FileName": "' + filename + '" }'
```

because correspond to the [JSON specification](http://www.json.org/) the property names must be also double quoted.

Next problem can you has if the `filename` has some special characters. For example, in case of

```
var filename = '"C:\\Program Files"'; // the '\' must be escaped in the string literal
```

you should has as the data the corresponding JSON string

```
'{ "FileName": "\\"C:\\\\Program Files\\"" }'
```

as the corresponding JSON data because of '\' and '"' **must** be escaped. It looks dificult. So I **stricly recommend** you to construct JSON strings with respect of [JSON.stringify](http://www.json.org/js.html) function from the [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js). Then the code will be

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ws.asmx/HelloWorld",
    data: JSON.stringify({ FileName: filename }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.d);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error Occured!" + " | " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText +
               " | " + textStatus + " | " +  errorThrown);
    }
});
```

which is simple and clear enough. The next advantage of the usage `JSON.stringify` is that the most modern web browsers has **native** support of the function and the function work very quickly.

By the way in case of the usage of `JSON.stringify` you can easy call web service methd having very complex data structures (classes) as the parameters and not only strings.

**UPDATED**: One more remrk to reduce possible misunderstanding. It you later deceide to use HTTP GET instead of HTTP POST to call the web method you will have to change the `data` parameter from

```
JSON.stringify({ FileName: filename })
```

to

```
{ FileName: JSON.stringify(filename) }
```

**UPDATED 2**: You can download [this](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jQuery/AsmxWebService.zip) Visual Studio 2010 project which I used to test all before I posted my answer. I included as "Web-3.5.config" the web.config for .NET 3.5. All different commented `data` values included in the default.htm work. If you want make tests with HTTP GET you should uncomment the section in web.config which allows HttpGet and use `ScriptMethod` having `UseHttpGet = true`. All the lines are included in the demo as comments.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Oleg, but I'm not sure this is the cause of the issue. The FileName is literally a string of alphanumeric characters, and when viewing the POST request in FireFox FireBug it shows a POST request, with the correct JSON data being sent.

Comment: @Curt: Which data exactly you see posted? You can vertfy the string in http://www.jsonlint.com/. The string like `{FileName: "bla"}` or `{'FileName': 'bla'}` are **NOT** valid JSON. The string `{"FileName": "bla"}` is correct. You confuse the JSON-like JavaScript syntax with the data-interchange format JSON described [here](http://www.json.org/). ASMX web service accept only correct JSON data.

Comment: @Curt: Do you tried my suggestions? I did it before writing my answer. If it help you I could upload the test VS2010 project C# which I used and post URL to it. Or do you have no interest in the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your help with this @Oleg. I'm very interested in resolving this problem and have spent many hours working on doing so. I'm quite certain my JSON format is correct as it comes out [code]{"FileName" : "FileName-Here"}[/code]. Also, I have a similar project to this which works fine! Could it be anything to do with the .NET application? Perhaps a setting which is different in the web.config? Your helps much appreciated

Comment: @Curt: Which version of Visual Studio you use (VS2010, VS2008), which language (C#/VB) and which version of .NET is your destination (.NET 4.0/3.5)? If you suspect problems in your web.config you can include it in the body of your question.

Comment: @Curt: I appended my answer with [the url](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jQuery/AsmxWebService.zip) to the demo project which I used.

Comment: Thanks for your example @Oleg, it's been very helpful, however it doesnt seem to have changed anything. What I don't understand is that in my script the only function I have is 'HelloWorld'. If I put '/ws.asmx/Lorem' surely this should return a 'Web Service not found' error message, but instead its just a blank response? Your help is very much appreciated as always!

Comment: @Curt: If you change 'ws.asmx/HelloWorld' in my example to 'ws.asmx/Lorem' you will receive the error "... Unknown web method Lorem ...". If you change 'ws.asmx/HelloWorld' to 'blabla.asmx/HelloWorld' you will receive the error "... No web service found at /blabla.asmx/HelloWorld ...".

Comment: This is strange... I can't find any difference with the applications :/ FYI: $.load works fine..

Comment: @Curt: You can upload the project somewhere and post the url to it like I did. The problem which you have is sure not in the parts of code which you included in your question.

Answer (score 2):

just to try use:

```
$.getJSON("/ws.asmx/HelloWorld", function(data){
   alert(data);
});
```

Check if you get the data back.

Comment: I've tried this, and the response was still blank. The alert stated "null"

Comment: what do you get in your firebug. Do you have the good response ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [AJAX-Enabled Web Service](http://www.asp.net/ajax/tutorials/understanding-asp-net-ajax-web-services)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have loaded the jquery.js file properly.

Comment: Previous to the coded provided are other jquery actions so I'm certain this is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Does the service return a value? If not, it will just POST and not give you back anything, because there is no data to see...

Comment: The service is supposed to return the string "Hello World", but it doesn't. Also, like stated, if I change the service to something like "HelloWorld123" no error is returned. I'm used to seeing a .NET error returned stating "Web Service cannot be found" or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to watch for errors, you can add an error callback

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/ws.asmx/HelloWorld"
    , type: "POST"
    , contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    , data: '{ FileName: "' + filename + '" }'
    , dataType: 'json'
    , success: function (data) {

    }
    , error: function (a, b, c) {

    }
});
```

From jQuery:

> ```
> error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)Function 
>
> A function to be called if the request fails. The function receives
> ```
>
> three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery
>   1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a string describing the type of error
>   that occurred and an optional
>   exception object, if one occurred.
>   Possible values for the second
>   argument (besides null) are "timeout",
>   "error", "abort", and "parsererror".
>   This is an Ajax Event. As of jQuery
>   1.5, the error setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will
>   be called in turn. Note: This handler
>   is not called for cross-domain script
>   and JSONP requests.

Comment: I tried putting an alert in the error() function, but the alert didn't appear, therefore I assume this was a success response, but blank!

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere that the contentType header for POST ***must*** be:
  `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');`

and I use it blindly: it's always worked.

-- pete