# autosuggest, ws and json problem

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services, json

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/webservices/AutoSuggestWebService.asmx/GetSuggestedRestaurants",
        data: "{'prefixText': '" + $('#ctl00_ctl00_cplMPBody_txtSearch').val() + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            data = msg.d;
            alert(msg.d)
            $("#ctl00_ctl00_cplMPBody_txtSearch").autocomplete(data);
        }
    })
```

where data is

```
["some text","another some textz","huh just text"]
```

WS:

```
[WebMethod]
        public string GetSuggestedRestaurants(object prefixText)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string json = js.Serialize(new RestaurantSearchHelper(DaoFactory).GetSearchSuggest(prefixText.ToString(), PageBase.CurrentCountry));
        }
```

but if i search by word "so" i don't get anything.

If ws return

```
[WebMethod]
        public string GetSuggestedRestaurants(object prefixText)
        {
            return  "Aeroplane dkhashd Apple Ambulance Border Crops Desalination Elephants  Parrot ";
        }
```

and js looks like

```
data = msg.d.split(" ");
alert(data)
```

then data looks like

```
Aeroplane,dkhashd,Apple,Ambulance,Border,Crops,Desalination,Elephants,Parrot
```

and autosuggest work. What is worng with first json if data is

```
["some text","another some textz","huh just text"]
```

Comment: Why aren't you running the second result string through the js serialize method?

Comment: second examle is just for test. first example must work but it does not and i do not know what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first error is that the text

```
{'prefixText': 'bla bla'}
```

is **NOT** valid JSON string. It could be correct [object initializer](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.1.5) in JavaScript, but it is wrong encoded JSON corresponds to http://www.json.org/ and [RFC4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627). Correct JSON string will be

```
{"prefixText": "bla bla"}
```

or the following

```
data: '{"prefixText": "' + $('#ctl00_ctl00_cplMPBody_txtSearch').val() + '"}'
```

in your case (with some small possible problems if `$('#ctl00_ctl00_cplMPBody_txtSearch').val()` has " or \ characters inside). I recommend you http://www.jsonlint.com/ site where you can validate any JSON data.

The next problem is on the server side. The ASMX web method should be like the following

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod (ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<string> GetSuggestedRestaurants(string prefixText) {
    return new RestaurantSearchHelper(DaoFactory).GetSearchSuggest(
                   prefixText,
                   PageBase.CurrentCountry);
}
```

and the corresponding class should has `[ScriptService]` attribute.

I recommend you to use `JSON.stringify` method:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ prefixText: $('#ctl00_ctl00_cplMPBody_txtSearch').val() })
```

instead of manual JSON serialization. See details in my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119977/jquery-ajax-response-always-returns-nothing/5127142#5127142) which include link to the working demo project.