# Showing Loading Image in Modal Popup Extender in Webservice ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I use .ajax to call a webservice mehod that sends an email to entered email.

I want to to show an ajax modal popup extender containg an image saying 'sendig...'

i used .ajax to call my webservice like:

```
var SendingModal = $find('SendMPE');
    var Resend = -1;
    $.ajax({
             async: false,
             type: "POST",
             url: "FinKaynWebService.asmx/SendEmail",
             data: "{'Email': '" + Email + "'}",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             beforeSend: function() {
                 $("#SendMPE").show();
             },
             success: function(response) {
                 Resend = response.d;
                 SendingModal.hide();
              },
              failure: function(msg) {
                 alert('Sending Email failed,try later');
              }
    });
```

the problem is that my SendMPE is not showing.

```
<div id="SendingDiv" style="display:none;background-color:Yellow;color:Blue;">
     <img id="LoadingImage" alt="Still sending"  src="./Images/Sending.gif" />
    <span style="margin-left:10px;">Sending...</span>
    <asp:Button ID="CloseButton" runat="server" style="display:none;" />
</div>
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="SendMPE" X="200" Y="200" runat="server" 
                    TargetControlID="SendHiddenButton" PopupControlID="SendingDiv" 
           CancelControlID="CloseButton"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

is this this problem caused by the image or what?

Who has an idea or has already done somthin like that:loading image in a popoup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should use

```
data: '{"Email": "' + Email + '"}'
```

or better

```
data: JSON.stringify({Email: Email})
```

instead of

```
data: "{'Email': '" + Email + "'}"
```

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119977/jquery-ajax-response-always-returns-nothing/5127142#5127142) for details.

One more remark. The event `beforeSend(jqXHR, settings)` should be use to modify jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object before it is sent (see [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) documantation). In your case you can just place `$("#SendMPE").show();` before the `$.ajax` call.

Moreover probably you want use `$("#SendingDiv").show();`?

Comment: the webservice method is executing when i debug.$("#SendMPE").show() the problem is just that the div is not showing.there is another popup that shows after the email is sent but not this one.

Comment: @user594166: Sorry, then you debug another code as you posted here. The result should be an error `{"Message":"Unrecognized escape sequence. (19): {\u0027Email\u0027: \u0027\Your.email@domain.com"\u0027}","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer...`. But because you use not existing `failure: function(msg)` instead of `error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)` you will never see any errors. I seenn in your other question you used `JSON.stringify` so you know this. Probably your do debug not the code which you posted.

Comment: @user594166: Do you tried with `$("#SendingDiv").show();` before `$.ajax` instead of `$("#SendMPE").show()` inside of `beforeSend`. Alternative you can use `SendingModal = $("#SendingDiv"); SendingModal.show();`?

Comment: i have removed beforesend.No @Oleg,to show a modal popup extender we use var SendingModal = $find('SendMPE'); $("#SendingModal").show(); I call now  $("#SendingModal").show() before .ajax but nothing happens.

Comment: @user594166: Probably you have "div#SendingDiv" concealed with another elements. Try to add style="z-index:1100;" to the "div#SendingDiv".

Comment: i have added the z-index:1100 .and i removed the modal popup.<div id="SendingDiv" style="background-color:red;width:100px;top:100px;
               left:200px;position:absolute;padding:20px;color:Blue;z-index:1100;display:none;">
            <img id="LoadingImage" alt="Still sending"  src="./Images/Sending.gif" />            <span style="margin-left:10px;">Sending...</span>
            
        </div><br/>$("#SendMeButton").live("click", function(event) { event.preventDefault(); $("#SendingDiv").show(); .it deosn' work but when i call it from link it works.

Comment: @user594166: I suppose you have some problem in the part which you not posted in the text of your question. I personally use [jQuery BlockUI Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) to show/hide for the purpose. It work very good. Sometime I use more simple div (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473690/jqgrid-need-to-change-progress-message-loading/4474749#4474749))

Comment: i found out that it show but it hides quickly before it loads.Howa can i wait until it loads(shows) then call .ajax

Comment: @user594166: You can include `alert("bla bla");` in the corresponding place before `$.ajax`. You can also include `alert` at the beginning of `success` handler.

Comment: Here is the fix for guys who meet the same problem:wait untill the sending divs show before calling .ajax  $("#SendingDiv").show('200', function() {
                        $.ajax({...});
                    });

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should remove 'style="display:none;' from SendingDiv. ModalPopupExtender will hide this div on startup.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you have in mind, but I typically follow the following general pattern. I have the request as a generic function (unimportant for your purpose), but have methods of callbacks handle process/error with the handler itself being instantiated being responsible for showing the modal.

AJAX Call:

```
var data = $.toJSON("{'obj:' + obj + "}");
var URI = "/FinKaynWebService.asmx/SendEmail";
var MSG = $("#modalDiv")
ajaxRequest(data, URI, new genericHandler(msg));
```

AJAX function:

```
function ajaxRequest(requestData, serviceURI, handler) {

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: serviceURI,
    data: requestData,
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
      callbackFunction.Process(result);
    },
    error: function(msg) {
      callbackFunction.OnError(msg.responseText)
    }
  });

}
```

Handler:

```
function genericHandler(msg) {
  $.blockUI(msg)
  this.Process = function(d) { alert("Data updated sucessfully.") };
  this.OnError = function(d) { alert(d.toString()) };
}
```

Comment: the problem is not that the call  deosn't happens.The call happens,and the email is sent.the problem is that my sendingdiv doesn't show when i call .show() in send button click event.When i call it in another link click event,my sending div shows.